# Kotlin - Function's Invoke Operator Overloading

Tags: operator-overloading, kotlin

I am currently studying [Kotlin - Operator Overloading](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html) 
I am trying to understand (with an example) how does operator overloading work for a function's `invoke()` function

**The pre-test**

- [Kotlin's Extension Functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html)

  ```
  fun exampleOfExtensionFunction() {
      fun Int.randomize(): Int {
          return Random(this.toLong()).nextInt()
      }

      val randomizedFive = 5.randomize()
      println("$randomizedFive")
  }
  ```

  Prints :

  > -1157408321
- [In Kotlin, functions can be declared as variables with types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-types)

  ```
  fun exampleOfFunctionType() {
      val printNumber: (number: Int) -> Unit
      printNumber = { number ->
          println("[$number = ${number.toString(16).toUpperCase()} = ${number.toString(2)}]")
      }

      printNumber(1023)
  }
  ```

  Prints :

  > [1023 = 3FF = 1111111111]
- [Kotlin allows operator overloading with both extension and member functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#operator-overloading)

  ```
  fun exampleOfOperatorOverloadingUsingExtensionFunction() {
      class MyType() {
          val strings: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList<String>()
          override fun toString(): String {
              val joiner: StringJoiner = StringJoiner(" , ", "{ ", " }")
              for (string in strings) {
                  joiner.add("\"$string\"")
              }
              return joiner.toString()
          }
      }

      operator fun MyType.contains(stringToCheck: String): Boolean {
          for (stringElement in strings) {
              if (stringElement == stringToCheck) return true
          }
          return false
      }

      val myType = MyType()
      myType.strings.add("one")
      myType.strings.add("two")
      myType.strings.add("three")
      println("$myType")
      println("(myType.contains(\"four\")) = ${myType.contains("four")} , (\"three\" in myType) = ${"three" in myType}")
  }
  ```

  Prints :

  > { "one" , "two" , "three" }
  >   (myType.contains("four")) = false , ("three" in myType) = true

**Test Attempt**
Based on the above. I tried to create an example of a function's `invoke()` operator overloading using the type `(Boolean, Boolean, Boolean) -> Boolean` as a receiver type for an extension function `invoke(flag1: Boolean, flag2: Boolean, flag3: Boolean)`. This however did not work as expected.

```
    fun attemptFunctionInvokeOperatorOverloading() {
        operator fun ((Boolean, Boolean, Boolean) -> Boolean).invoke(flag1: Boolean, flag2: Boolean, flag3: Boolean): Boolean {
            println("Overloaded invoke operator")
            return flag1 && flag2 && flag3
        }

        var func1: ((Boolean, Boolean, Boolean) -> Boolean) = { flag1, flag2, flag3 ->
            println("func1 body")
            flag1 && flag2 && flag3
        }

        fun func2(flag1: Boolean, flag2: Boolean, flag3: Boolean): Boolean {
            println("func2 body")
            return flag1 && flag2 && flag3
        }

        func1(true, true, false)
        func2(true, true, true)
    }
```

Prints :

> func1 body
>   func2 body

Expected :

> Overloaded invoke operator
>   Overloaded invoke operator

**Another question** :
What exactly is this? (If it isn't operator overloading)

```
        operator fun ((Boolean, Boolean, Boolean) -> Boolean).invoke(flag1: Boolean, flag2: Boolean, flag3: Boolean): Boolean {
            println("Overloaded invoke operator")
            return flag1 && flag2 && flag3
        }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As said in another answer, invoke is defined on the function object itself, so you can't override it with an extension method.

I think the deeper problem here, though, is a slight misunderstanding of the purpose of this feature. Let's look at `plus` for the `+` operator instead.

I think you'll agree that attempting to define `operator fun Int.plus(b: Int): Int { /* ... */}` makes no sense, because overriding the default `+` operator for ints is a pretty dangerous thing to do, yes?

However, if you define a complex number class:

```
data class Complex(real: Double, img: Double)
```

Then it's perfectly reasonable to define this to sum complex numbers:

```
operator fun Complex.plus(other: Complex): Complex {
  val real = this.real + other.real
  val img  = this.img + other.img
  return Complex(real, img)
}
```

So, same thing with `invoke` and `()`: The meaning of `()` is that it's whatever is analogous to invoking a function for your type, and overriding `invoke` on something that's already a function is just asking for trouble. What you want to use it for instead is to provide function-like syntax for your own objects.

For example, imagine you define an interface like so:

```
interface MyCallback {
  fun call(ctx: MyContext)
}
```

Which you use the usual way:

```
callback.call(ctx)
```

But with an implementation of the `invoke` operator overload, you get to use it as a function:

```
operator fun MyCallback.invoke(ctx: Context) = this.call(ctx)

/* Elsewhere... */
callback(ctx)
```

Hope that clarifies how you use `invoke`/`()`

Answer (score 3):

Your issue has to to with resolution precedence. [According to the Kotlin docs](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extensions-are-resolved-statically):

> If a class has a member function, and an extension function is defined which has the same receiver type, the same name and is applicable to given arguments, the **member always wins**.

So your `operator fun ((Boolean, Boolean, Boolean) -> Boolean).invoke(...)` extension function is never called because the member `invoke` takes precedence.

**Another Answer**

It is indeed operator overloading, but through an extension. Again, since `(Boolean, Boolean, Boolean) -> Boolean` already has a `fun invoke(Boolean, Boolean, Boolean): Boolean` defined, your extension loses.

Comment: The reason for this is that, if an extension had a higher precedence than a member function, the result of a function call could be indeterminate and could change by simply including another library in your project without you being aware (assuming the extension was in scope or imported).

Comment: Does this mean that it is impossible to effectively overload the invoke function? Because every time the member function takes precedence. And because there is no way to define a class of a function type in kotlin then implement operator overloading as a member function of a function.

Comment: For functional types yes, but any class that has an open invoke function can be overridden. The point of functional types is to accept anything that matches the signature. As with anything else, if you want specific functionality, you create a class with that functionality.